# Android app crashing on receiving intent bundle?

Tags: javascript, android, string, android-intent, crash

I will preface this by saying I am a complete newb, this is my first project, and I have tried searching everywhere to answer my question.

I have a login screen set up on android.  Once the user hits the login button and the login name/password are correct, (validated in PHP/SQL) it sends an intent/bundle to the next activity.

Here is the code to send the intent/bundle:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
Intent intent2 = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
intent2.putExtra("username2", username2);
startActivity(intent);
```

Here is the code to receive the intent bundle on the next activity:

```
   Intent intent2 = getIntent(); 
   String usernamefromlogin = intent2.getExtras().getString("username2");
   String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
   TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorchecking);
   text.setText(url5);
```

I am using concat() to put a URL before the intent bundle because that URL is going to be used as a _GET command to a PHP file (but I digress).  Currently, I have it set to place the text into a TextView so that I can see what the end result is, but the app crashes before I can get to that point.

My app crashes when I hit the login button.  Here is the Logcat I am getting:

```
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578): Process: com.sencide, PID: 4578
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sencide/com.sencide.Homepage}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2176)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2226)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:135)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1397)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4998)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:777)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:593)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at com.sencide.Homepage.onCreate(Homepage.java:46)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5243)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2140)
11-30 20:06:39.449: E/AndroidRuntime(4578):     ... 11 more
11-30 20:06:42.569: I/Process(4578): Sending signal. PID: 4578 SIG: 9
```

Here is my entire code:

AndroidLogin.java

```
public class AndroidLogin extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


Button ok,back,exit;
TextView result;
String thisisausername;



/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
   setContentView(R.layout.main);



    // Login button clicked
    ok = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    ok.setOnClickListener(this);


    result = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbl_result);



}









public void postLoginData() {
    // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

   // login.php returns true if username and password match in db 
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php");

    try {




        // Add user name and password
        EditText uname = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
        String username = uname.getText().toString();



        EditText pword = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_password);
        String password = pword.getText().toString();

        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        Log.w("SENCIDE", "Execute HTTP Post Request");
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
        Log.w("SENCIDE", str);

        if(str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("true"))
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "TRUE");
            result.setText("Login Successful! Please Wait...");   
        }else
        {
            Log.w("SENCIDE", "FALSE");
            result.setText(str);                
        }

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
} 

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) { 
            total.append(line); 
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // Return full string
    return total;
}


public void RegisterButton(View view) {
    String url = "http://10.0.2.2/register.php";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);   
}




@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
            postLoginData();




            // turns the text in the textview "Tbl_result" into a text string called "tblresult"
            TextView tblresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tbl_result);




    // If "tblresult" text string matches the string "Login Successful! Please Wait..." exactly, it will switch to next activity
            if (tblresult.getText().toString().equals("Login Successful! Please Wait...")) {
                  Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
                  EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
                  String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
                  intent.putExtra("username2", username2);
                  startActivity(intent);
               }    






}



}
```

Homepage.Java

```
public class Homepage extends Activity {






//URL to get JSON Arrays
public static String url = "http://x.x.x.x/SQL.php?username=123";



//JSON Node Names 
private static final String TAG_USER = "users";
private static final String TAG_ID = "uid";
private static final String TAG_NAME = "fullname";
private static final String TAG_DISPLAY = "displayname";
private static final String TAG_EMAIL = "email";
private static final String TAG_PW = "password";
private static final String TAG_CREATED = "created_at";
private static final String TAG_UPDATED = "updated_at";


JSONArray user = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


   //Get login name from EditText in login screen and concatenate it to PHP user-name for _GET 
   Intent intent2 = getIntent(); 
   String usernamefromlogin = intent2.getExtras().getString("username2");
   String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
   TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorchecking);
   text.setText(url5);


    setContentView(R.layout.reshomepage);

    // Creating new JSON Parser
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();

    // Getting JSON from URL
    JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

    try {
        // Getting JSON Array
        user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);
        JSONObject c = user.getJSONObject(0);

        // Storing  JSON item in a Variable
        String uid = c.getString(TAG_ID);
        String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
        String display = c.getString(TAG_DISPLAY);
        String email = c.getString(TAG_EMAIL);
        String pw = c.getString(TAG_PW);
        String created = c.getString(TAG_CREATED);
        String updated = c.getString(TAG_UPDATED);



        //Importing TextView
        final TextView uid1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvuid);
        final TextView name1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvfullname);
        final TextView display1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvdisplayname);
        final TextView email1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvemail);
        final TextView pw1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvpassword);
        final TextView created1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvcreated_at);
        final TextView updated1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvupdated_at);


        //Set JSON Data in TextView
        uid1.setText(uid);
        name1.setText(name);
        display1.setText(display);
        email1.setText(email);
        pw1.setText(pw);
        created1.setText(created);
        updated1.setText(updated);


} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

}

}
```

JSONParser.java

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

public JSONObject getJSONFromUrl(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

Main.XML (first login screen)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<!-- Text at Top !-->    
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/lbl_top" 
android:textSize="16sp" 
android:typeface="sans" 
android:text="Please Login" 
/>

<!-- Username Text Above Field  !-->
<TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/lbl_username" 
android:text="User Name (e-mail)" 
/>    

<!-- Username Field  !-->
<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:textSize="18sp" 
android:id="@+id/txt_username" 
/>

<!-- Password Text Above Field  !-->
<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:id="@+id/lbl_password" 
android:text="Password" 
/>

<!-- Password Field  !-->
<EditText 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:password="true" 
android:id="@+id/txt_password" 
/>

<!--  Login Button  !-->
<Button 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="35dp" 
android:id="@+id/btn_login" 
android:text="Login"
android:onClick="LoginScreenButton"
/>

<!--  Register Button  !-->

<Button 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="35dp" 
android:id="@+id/register" 
android:text="New Registration"
android:onClick="RegisterButton"
/>



<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tbl_result"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
/>

<TextView 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/tbl_result2"
android:textColor="#00FF00"
/>

</LinearLayout>
```

reshomepage.XML  (second screen where I am trying to send intent to)

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvuid"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvfullname"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvdisplayname"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvemail"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvpassword"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvcreated_at"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvupdated_at"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/errorchecking"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is You creade 2 intents (intent and intent2) and then saved the username in intent2, but startActivity(intent) is being called.

So basically, remove one of the intents and your code should look something like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("username2", username2);
startActivity(intent);
```

Let me know how this goes

Comment: Thank you for the quick response, I am now getting this error in Logcat:

http://postimg.org/image/6mjn5unzn/full/



Any ideas?


I added the entirety of my code as well

Comment: Is line 49: `user = json.getJSONArray(TAG_USER);`? if it is, plz paste a demo of the json data. if line 49 has something to do with the ui, plz paste your layout xml code.

Comment: Thank you so much @Aftab for helping.

I just posted the rest of my code.

Line 49 on my main.xml file is the login button in the first activity.

Comment: I meant line 49 in `HomePage.java`. Not sure if you added extra lines or removed any. The LogCat shows which line caused the error, which makes it easy to fix. So, if you made any changes to the code, run the app again and from the logCat, give me the line that caused the error. Should be something like.. `Caused by .... (HomePage.Java: 49)`

Comment: Looks like "text.setText(url5);" is line 49.

so it's having problem setting the text to the text view?  What could be a cause for this?

I even tried removing " TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorchecking);" and replacing the setText with "errorchecking.setText(url5);" but I get the error still on the same line.

My guess is that the string url5 is not in a correct format, any way to find out how?

Comment: if `text.setText(url5);` is giving the NullPointerException (which means you're trying to Get or Set a non-initialized item - which still holds a null value) ... If we look at this code, you have 2 variables on this line (text and url5). a way to check which one is null, I use `Log.d("Error_Key_Here", url5);` and this will tell you if url5 is null or not .. if it isn't then `text` is null

Comment: so url5 is fine, it's displaying the link just like I want.  When I try to type "Log.d("ERROR KEY 1", texts);" to check texts, it gives me an error in Eclipse: 

"The method d(String, String) in the type Log is not applicable for the arguments (String, TextView)"  

I don't know why this would work with url5 but not texts.

Comment: Text is a text view and the Log.d() method takes two strings. So in the 2nd parameter you'll need to get the text from the TextView by calling text.get text(),,, now for the nullexception... I'm kind of bust right now so I'll check in a bit. But 1 thing we know now is that the TextView is the one that's null

Comment: Please take your time, I am in no hurry.  You are teaching me a lot and I appreciate it.

I think I found the problem, I just don't know how to fix it.

So I have this code to convert the intent into a string called "usernamefromlogin":

"usernamefromlogin=intent.getExtras().getString("username2"); "

I check my intent in Log.d and it comes out fine.
       
But whenever I try to use the variable "usernamefromlogin," I get the error.  Even when I setup a Log.D on it.

So how come "intent.getExtras().getString("username2");" is causing "usernamefromlogin" to be null?  

What u think is wrong?

Comment: One thing I should let you know is that I'm a rookie in coding too :P Now that I'm awake, I think I see the problem in the code. Always have `setContentView(...)` before making any UI changes (anything that interacts with items on the screen. ex.: changing text, button onClick, ....). So in this case put `setContentView(R.layout...)` after the `super.onCreate()` method and then, work with the UI components. It should fix the Error. `super.onCreate --> setContentView --> the other stuff`

Comment: Thank you so much, you have helped me get through this issue.  I now have another error that is popping up that is related to my previous issue.

"12-01 15:19:40.979: E/JSON Parser(7305): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value <br of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONObject"

If I remove my intent-passing code, the error goes away and the program runs.  

I researched the error and it looks like something in the array is causing the parse to cancel (probably a PHP page given the "<br")

So my new question is how can I find/fix this array problem.

Comment: Like you said, `<br ` is not JSON. a complete JSON Object looks something like: JSONObject ={
"name":"John Johnson",
"street":"Oslo West 555",
"age":33,
"phone":"555 1234567"};
If the document returned has HTML in the beginning, you'll somehow need to get the JSON object out of the source code. I'm sorry, but I have no knowledge in that yet :( I only know how to read JSON data (alone) for now lol

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is that you've attached the username2 extra to intent2, but you dont use intent2.

You start your activity and then look for the extra 'username2' in the incoming intent, since the intent you sent didn't contain the extra 'username2' you get usernamefromlogin assigned a value of null, and causing the null pointer exception you see in your stack trace.

Just get rid of the second intent, and place your string extra in the one that you use when starting the activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Homepage.class);
EditText uname2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txt_username);
String username2 = uname2.getText().toString();
intent.putExtra("username2", username2);
startActivity(intent);
```

For the sake of safety, maybe make sure the intent HAS the extra before you run off and use it.

```
Intent intent = getIntent(); 
if (intent.hasExtra("username2") {
   String usernamefromlogin = intent.getExtras().getString("username2");
   String url5 = url.concat(usernamefromlogin);
   TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.errorchecking);
   text.setText(url5);
} else {
    // ...appropriate error handling goes here!
}
```

good luck!